# Disable/enable tabs: change color to original

Tags: android, colors, tabs, android-tabhost

I've got the following code:

```
\\Disable
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(false);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(102, 102, 102));
```

And:

```
\\Enable
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(true);
\\HOWTO?
```

How can I revert the color of the disabled tab back to it's original color (with gradient and stuff) when I enable it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Drawable as background you can use:

```
savedBackground = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).getBackground();
// Disable your tab
```

And once you enable it:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(true);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).getChildTabViewAt(3).setBackgroundDrawable (savedBackground );
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I tried something like that, but got errors. It works anyway when I do it like this!

Answer (score 1):

You can't extract a Color value from the original enabled tab, as it uses a Drawable. However, I don't believe anything is stopping you from switching between a Drawable and a Color for enabled/disabled states. So my suggestion is to store the original background Drawable from the tab View using View.getBackground(), and when it comes time to enable the tab again, you can then pass that stored drawable to View.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable).